How do I connect to google drive through the file application?
How to I connect to google drive? I opened -Files- and selected -other locations.

google-drive-ocalmfuse is a FUSE file system for Google Drive that allows you to easily mount it on your file system so you can access it.
It is necessary to install the application and its dependencies
Open a terminal and run in it:
sudo apt update

sudo apt install google-drive-ocamlfuse

One time only, you must run in the terminal:
google-drive-ocamlfuse

This command creates the directory for the application ~/.gdfuse/default, with the configuration file and starts the internet browser to access Google Drive.
From now on, running in a terminal:
/bin/google-drive-ocamlfuse /home/youruser/gdrive

You can mount the Google Drive file system
